# Join lines automatically using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Long paragraphs in Adobe Acrobat results in a line break when text is copied to clipboard and pasted in Word.

To deal with this, I manually paste the copied-text in Notepad ++ > select all > ctrl+J (join lines) > select all > Copy...... and then paste it into my Word document.

I would like to automate this join line using autohotkey as I have a large body of documents to go through. I can't seem to find any examples online in dealing with this directly within autohotkey script.

Ex.

```
Data structures with labeled axes supporting automatic or explicit data alignment.
This prevents common errors resulting from misaligned data and working with
differently-indexed data coming from different sources.
```

After manually joining in Notepad ++

```
Data structures with labeled axes supporting automatic or explicit data alignment. This prevents common errors resulting from misaligned data and working with differently-indexed data coming from different sources.
```

Comment: found an answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1109920/235752

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
#Persistent
OnClipboardChange("ClipChanged")
return

ClipChanged() {

    If (WinActive("ahk_exe AcroRd32.exe")) {
        For e, v in StrSplit(clipboard, "`n", "`r")
            x .= v " "
        clipboard := trim(x)
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's missing an OnClipboardChange function. Is that a default function. Maybe I'm using an outdated AHK

Comment: It's in the latest versions of AHK, several earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#Persistent
return

    OnClipboardChange:
If WinActive("ahk_exe AcroRd32.exe")
{
    clipboard =
    Send, {Ctrl down}c{Ctrl up}{Esc}
        ClipWait
    clip := RegExReplace(clipboard, "(\S.*?)\R(.*?\S)", "$1 $2") ; strip line breaks and replace them with spaces
    clipboard = %clip%  
    StringReplace clipboard, clipboard, % "  ", % " ", A         ; replace double spaces with single spaces 
        ClipWait
    ControlClick, x0 y0, A
}
return
```

**EDIT**

Or this:

```
#Persistent
return

    OnClipboardChange:
If WinActive("ahk_class AcrobatSDIWindow")
{
    clipboard := ""
    Send, {Ctrl down}c{Ctrl up}{Esc}
        ClipWait
    clip := RegExReplace(clipboard, "(\S.*?)\R(.*?\S)", "$1 $2") ; strip line breaks and replace them with spaces
    StringReplace clip, clip, % "  ", % " ", A         ; replace double spaces with single spaces 
    clipboard := "" 
    clipboard = %clip% 
    ClipWait 2
    If !(ErrorLevel)
    {
        ToolTip, lines joined
        Sleep 500
        ToolTip
    }
}
return
```

Comment: I switched the "ahk_exe AcroRd32.exe" to "ahk_class AcrobatSDIWindow" and it worked. The only thing is that when I copy the clipboard. It switches the cursor for acrobat from Text to Pan (Hand). Not sure why that is occurring. Also, if I copy and move to notepad too quickly (before the clipboard process finishes) the join line does not occur. I'll see what I can figure out. Thanks!

Comment: Try  my edited answer. @ahkcoder's code works for me, too. [This](https://autohotkey.com/download/) is the latest AHK version.

Answer (score 0):

I added functionality considering lines ending with a hyphen.

Before:

```
This occurs in elec-
tricity generation
systems.
```

After:

```
This occurs in electricity generation systems.
```

Code:

```
#Persistent
return

    OnClipboardChange:
If WinActive("ahk_exe AcroRd32.exe")
{
    clipboard := ""
    Send, {Ctrl down}c{Ctrl up}{Esc}
        ClipWait
    clip := RegExReplace(clipboard, "(\S.*?)-\R(.*?\S)", "$1$2") ; strip line breaks with hyphen
    clip := RegExReplace(clip, "(\S.*?)\R(.*?\S)", "$1 $2") ; strip line breaks and replace them with spaces
    StringReplace clip, clip, % "  ", % " ", A ; replace double spaces with single spaces 
    clipboard := "" 
    clipboard = %clip% 
    ClipWait 2
    If !(ErrorLevel)
    {
        ToolTip, lines joined
        Sleep 500
        ToolTip
    }
}
return
```